# Dynamically define a Union of Literal string permutations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typing, pylance

I have a list of strings:

```py
strings = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to declare a `Union` of `Literal` types of all the possible ordered pairs of the list. Hardcoded, this would look like:

```py
CustomType = Literal[
  'ab', 'ac', 'aa',
  'ba', 'bb', 'bc',
  'ca', 'cb', 'cc'
]
```

How could I define `CustomType` dynamically such that I don't have to manually put each combination?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```py
CustomType = Literal[*permutations(strings)]
```

but that gives me the error:

```
Unpack operator in subscript requires Python 3.11 or newer 
 Pylance
Unpacked arguments cannot be used in type argument lists 
 Pylance
```

The objective motivating this question is to have Pylance detect if I try passing a string that is not an element of that set.

```py
def f(string: CustomType):
  ...

f('foo') # Pylance will complain
f('ba') # Pylance will permit
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you turn it into a type, but you want `''.join(s for s in itertools.product(strings, repeat=2))`

Comment: I love Python, but recently I've seen lots of questions like this, how to do X in Python typing, where there isn't really any simple way to answer, but would be easy in TypeScript. It makes me sad, and is a good reminder for the fact that TypeScript's type system is *awesome*. You can't do this in Python; you can't do it in C++; you can't do it in Java; you **can** do it in TypeScript. (Not saying there's no way to answer this question, but it's not as simple as TypeScript)

Comment: This has kinda become my mantra recently: **Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.** In other words, there is _no_ way. Dynamic type annotations are a contradiction in terms, no matter what TypeScript snobs want to claim.  It's not that this is not possible because _Virgin Python vs. Chad TypeScript_... It is because the only way to infer dynamically created types is to run the code. Statically typed languages can obviously define their own mechanisms to declare types ahead of time that don't require executing the code. Python is not that. Apples vs. Oranges.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg why can't language servers, i.e Pylance, infer it? That's all I'm looking for, I understand that it won't have any runtime implication. I just want the IDE feedback while developing.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I'm not a TypeScript snob, as I said, I love Python. I also didn't say TypeScript has dynamic type annotations, because, as you said, that is impossible. TypeScript's type system is just very powerful.

Comment: `Literal` only matches *literals*, not arbitrary values that happen to be equal to the value used to construct the `Literal`. It's not meant to be an arbitrary type constructor.

Comment: @chepner the values are not arbitrary, they are the literal elements of the list attempting to be unpacked. If you can do `Literal['a','b','c']`, it would make sense and be very useful to be able to do `Literal[*ls]` where `ls = ['a','b','c']`.

Comment: I'm not even talking about how to built the type hint. If you have a function like `def foo(x: Literal['x'])`, then `foo('x')` type-checks, but `arg='x'; foo(arg)` will not.

Comment: @chepner I've just tested that in my IDE and confirmed that Pylance *does* type-check `arg='x'; foo(arg)`. https://imgur.com/a/yJDJR48

Comment: This can be done by implementing custom ast rules, however I think pylance / pyright doesn't support it, are you fine with a mypy implementation?

Comment: @Achxy_ I'd certainly like to see it, although I do ultimately want IDE feedback, ideally with Pylance.

Answer (score 3):

The exact approach you're looking for is not possible in Python [yet], according to the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#parameterizing-literals).
Official code interacts with some similar issues, and the answer is just to write out every permutation, like [official stubs in typeshed by core team do](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/918f2266da5d0a3ed4cb5fd9b756f1e0ceae5097/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L135).

However, you can get close using something like a `Sequence`:

```py
CustomType = Sequence[Literal['a', 'b', 'c']]

func(('a', 'b', 'c'))
func(('d', 'e'))  # fails
func(('a',))
func(['a', 'b'])
```

Alas, you still can't use a string for the arguments:

```py
func('abc')  # fails — sequence of strings, not literals
func(tuple('abc'))  # fails — tuple derived from a string becomes sequence of strings, not the needed CustomFlags.
arg: CustomType = 'ab'  # fails, the str can't be assigned out.
```

If exactly two elements are needed, use a `Tuple`:

```py
CustomOption = Literal['a', 'b', 'c']
CustomType = Tuple[CustomOption, CustomOption]

func(('a', 'b'))
func(('a', 'b', 'c'))  # fails
```

Answer (score 1):

`Literal` accepts dynamic input from a tuple and you can use `itertools` to generate all combinations:

```py
from typing import Literal
from itertools import product

strings='abc'

Literal[tuple(x+y for x,y in product(strings, repeat=2))]
```

outputs `typing.Literal['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']`

### check with pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class NewClass(BaseModel):
    string: Literal[tuple(x + y for x, y in product("abc", repeat=2))]


NewClass(string="aa")
```

Comment: I'm getting `Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value Pylance` on that last line. Are you sure this is supported? What version of Python are you on?

Comment: I am on Python 3.9.5

Comment: I am testing it on 3.10.8 and getting that error. Have you confirmed that this works for you on your own machine using a language server like Pylance?

Comment: that must be an issue with Pylance then (not an issue with Python; because technically this works for example with pydantic)

Answer (score 0):

Running into a similar issue. My use case here is that I want to derive the `List[]` and `Literal[]` from the same source of truth so other functions that depend on the literal can also have access to the raw `List[]` without having to maintain 2 separate definitions. My initial idea was similar to what was proposed here: infer the *Literal* type from a defined *List*. However, Daniil Fajnberg makes a good point here:

> Dynamic type annotations are a contradiction

In light of this, perhaps it would be more appropriate to do the reverse: derive the *List* from the *Literal*:

```py
# Define the literal type
LiteralType = Literal['a', 'b', 'c']

# Cast the literal type to a list of values
values = eval(f"[{', '.join([repr(value) for value in LiteralType.__args__])}]")
```